# Jquery Datatables Insert , Update , Delete Code Ya Link In asp.net Dynamically

Tags: asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmqOf.png)
Here My image Plzz Help Me..

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good question (and therefore get good answers)

Answer (score -1):

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "first_name"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "last_name"
            }, {
                label: "Position:",
                name: "position"
            }, {
                label: "Office:",
                name: "office"
            }, {
                label: "Extension:",
                name: "extn"
            }, {
                label: "Start date:",
                name: "start_date",
                type: "datetime"
            }, {
                label: "Salary:",
                name: "salary"
            }
        ]
    } );

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        columns: [
            { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                // Combine the first and last names into a single table field
                return data.first_name+' '+data.last_name;
            } },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
        ],
        select: true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html

> note: this is in paid version

Comment: Mert Sir , I see That Code But I can't UnderStand That More Example Please Give Me. .....